# Deserialize serialized object giving Delayed::DeserializationError Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have stored the serialized objects in table so that we can access their attributes and values even after deleted. 
But when the record is deleted then its giving error "Delayed::DeserializationError" during deserializing it.
Searched lot to work around it but did not get any solution.

```
class ActivtyLog
  serialize :performer
  serialize :target
end

ActivityLog.create(performer: person, target: obj, action: "create",  change: "update")
```

when accessing

```
activity.target #gives the targeted deserialized object
activity.performer #gives the performer deserialized object
```

Comment: I have updated with sample code

Comment: I guess the question is, can you expect it to work after removing the origin? Is it like the documented behavior?

Comment: Yes as the object is serialized I should be able to access the object's properties.
Means if I serialize any non-AR object then we can access it any time then why shouldn't I be able to access AR object.